# Iterate over deep nested routes in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Ok, so I know this isn't preferred method, but my client needs fixed urls that can be indexed by Google and dynamic urls won't cut it. Everything works great, all my product resources work as they should, except on the 4th and final nest, I can't get a list of my objects on the subcategories/show route; I am sure I am missing something simple.

**routes**

```
resources :locations do
  resources :categories do
    resources :subcategories do
      resources :products
    end
  end
end
```

**subcategories/show view**
I need to list the `products` that belong to the `subcategory`

```
...
<h1><%= @subcategory.name %></h1>
<%= sanitize @subcategory.body %>

...
<% @location...@category...@subcategory.products.each do |p| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= p.name %></td>
    <td><%= p.slug %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', location_category_subcategory_product_path(@location, @category, @subcategory, p) %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
...
```

**subcategory model**

```
has_many :products
```

**products model**

```
belongs_to :subcategory
```

**products_controller**

```
 def index
    @location = Location.friendly.find(params[:location_id])
    @category = Category.friendly.find(params[:category_id])
    @subcategory = Subcategory.friendly.find(params[:subcategory_id])
    @products = Product.all
  end

  def show
    @location = Location.friendly.find(params[:location_id])
    @category = Category.friendly.find(params[:category_id])
    @subcategory = Subcategory.friendly.find(params[:subcategory_id])
    @product = Product.friendly.find(params[:id])
  end
```

Comment: Still not clear what exact issue you have in 'I can't get a list of my objects on the subcategories/show route'

Comment: @AntonTkachov Sorry, I forgot to show the error message `syntax error, unexpected ... '.freeze; @location...@category...@subcategory.products.each do |p| ` - when I am on a subcategory show page, I want to see a list of products that belong_to that subcategory. this gives me the error `http://127.0.0.1:3000/locations/san-diego/categories/theme-parties/subcategories/boy-themed` but this doesn't `http://127.0.0.1:3000/locations/san-diego/categories/theme-parties/subcategories/boy-themed/products/game-boy` - so its only when trying to list the subcategories products I see the error.

Comment: maybe not relevant, but why are you using this `@location...@category...@subcategory.products.each do |p|` instead of this `@subcategory.products.each do |p|` Your subcategory seem to be available for parse, not sure if mentioning the preceding objects is correct if even useful.

Comment: @Maxence I knew I was missing something...that may not have been the direct answer, but when I removed the reference to location and category, it quickly led me to the need to setup has_many :through relationships to products for location and category, which solved my problem.  I up-voted your comment.

Comment: great you managed to fix it. Actually I have had a recent question about the routing and the models parenthood. It should not necessary replicate each other https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47445720/do-i-need-my-routes-map-my-models-parenthood Actually One degre of route nesting is considered a good practice (I am changing my controllers and views and it takes a lot of time to do though)